# python execution directly via command line linux

Tags: python, linux

how can i run an easy python script and save it in a file but directly in linux command line:

```
fox@fox:/opt/gera# python -c print "aaaaa" > myfileName
```

but it is just print nothing instead of "aaaaa".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to quote the whole command:

```
python -c 'print "aaaaa"' > myfileName
```

Otherwise you execute `print` in Python (which, in Python 2 prints a linebreak and in Python 3 does nothing since you'd just evaluate the function `print` without calling it) and pass `aaaaa` as an argument to the script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around the code.

```
python -c 'print "aaaaa"' > myfileName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
python -c 'print "aaaaa"' > myfileName
```

in your example python is running `python -c print` and giving "aaaaa" as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

man python:

> -c command
>
> Specify the command to execute.  This terminates the option list (following options are **passed as arguments to the command**).

**passed as arguments to the command** -- means everything after the **command** is available as sys.argv:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv' -a -b -c -d
['-c', '-a', '-b', '-c', '-d']
```

To make a single argument (command in terms of the man excerpt above) out of a list of arguments you just take these in quotes:

```
$ python -c 'print "aaaaa"'
aaaaa
```